# dihedral group operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$ with $r^n=1, s^2=1$. Then since $rs=sr^{-1}$, $r^as^b=s^br^{(-1)^ba}.$ Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe adding details on how did you get to the formula (just guessed based on few specific values of $a$ and $b$? Or do you have your own complete proof? etc.), and within what context you came to that, could help in reopening the question. I think it could be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $b$ even, your formula holds for every $a$. For $b$ odd, your formula reads:

$$r^as=sr^{-a} \tag 1$$

Induction on $a$: for $a=1$, $(1)$ holds; let $(1)$ hold for $a$; then: 
\begin{alignat}{1}
r^{a+1}s &= r^ars \\
&= r^a(ss^{-1})rs \\
&= (r^as)s^{-1}rs \\
&= (sr^{-a})s^{-1}rs \\
&= (sr^{-a})s^{-1}rs^{-1} \\
&= sr^{-a}s^{-1}(rs^{-1}) \\
&= sr^{-a}s^{-1}(s^{-1}r^{-1}) \\
&= sr^{-a}(s^{-1}s^{-1})r^{-1} \\
&= sr^{-a}s^{-2}r^{-1} \\
&= sr^{-a}r^{-1} \\
&=sr^{-(a+1)}
\end{alignat}

so that $(1)$ holds for every $a$.

In conclusion, yes, to me your formula looks OK.